# Project Euler #22 Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have been trying to solve problem 22 of Project Euler and I know I'm close to the answer but I can't see where the mistake is in my code. Any ideas will be helpful (including Java naming conventions).

Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.

For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.

What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

My code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Problem22 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader numReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/names.txt"));
        String line = "";

        while ((line = numReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] dataNames = line.split(",");

            for (String item : dataNames) {
                String newItem = item.substring(1, item.length() - 1);
                names.add(newItem);
            }
        }
        numReader.close();

        Collections.sort(names);

        long bigSum = 0;
        int mult = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            int x = valueOfName(names.get(i));
            mult = x * i;

            bigSum += mult;
        }

        System.out.println("Sum: " + bigSum);
    }

    public static int valueOfName(String s) {
        char[] ABC = {'1', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

        char[] tempName = s.toCharArray();

        int sum = 0;
        for (char c : tempName) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ABC.length; j++) {
                if (c == ABC[j])
                    sum += j;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugging tool?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: No compiling errors. Just not getting the desire result. I'm getting 870873746 as output and the answe is 871198282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SPOILER ALERT. CORRECT ANSWER TO THE PROBLEM**

Thanks everyone who took the time to answer to my question. I've found the problem!

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){


        int x = valueOfName(names.get(i));
        mult = x * (i + 1); //Was missing "+1" because index starts at 0

        bigSum += mult;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `valueOfName()`:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= ABC.length; j++){

    if(c == ABC[j-1])
        sum += j-1;

}
```

Comment: Is it closer to the answer or farther away?

Comment: Actually, it throws an exception ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, beacuse you suggested to add an equal sign in the loop. And removing that sign, the answer is farther away.

Comment: What if you have ABC[j-1] instead?

Comment: It'll also throws an exception because arrays start at zero, and the for loop also starts at zero, so you are requesting a character that doesn't exists. (ArrayIndezOutOfBounds -1). And if I start my for loop at 1, the result continues to be wrong.

Comment: Congrats on finding the solution!